# repeat rows depending upon course duration in years

Tags: pandas

I have a dataframe that needs to repeat itself.

```
from io import StringIO
import pandas as pd

audit_trail = StringIO('''
course_id AcademicYear_to months TotalFee
260 2017 24 100
260 2018 12 140
274 2016 36 300
274 2017 24 340
274 2018 12 200
285 2017 24 300
285 2018 12 200
''')

df11 = pd.read_csv(audit_trail, sep=" "  )
```

For the course id 260 there are 2 entries per year. Year 2017 and Year 2018. I need to repeat the years for the month groups.
I will get 2 more rows, 2018 for months 24 and 2017 for months 12. The final dataframe will look like this...

```
audit_trail = StringIO('''
course_id AcademicYear_to months TotalFee
260 2017 24 100
260 2018 24 100
260 2017 12 140
260 2018 12 140
274 2016 36 300
274 2017 36 300
274 2018 36 300
274 2016 24 340
274 2017 24 340
274 2018 24 340
274 2016 12 200
274 2017 12 200
274 2018 12 200
285 2017 24 300
285 2018 24 300
285 2017 12 200
285 2018 12 200
''')

df12 = pd.read_csv(audit_trail, sep=" "  )
```

I tried to concat the same dataframe twice, but that does not solve the problem. I need to change the years and for 36 months, the data needs to be repeated 3 times.

```
pd.concat([df11, df11])
```

---

The group by object will return the years. I simply need to join the years in each group with the original dataframe.

```
df11.groupby('course_id')['AcademicYear_to'].apply(list)

260          [2017, 2018]
274    [2016, 2017, 2018]
285          [2017, 2018]
```

---

Simple join can work if the records match with the number of years. For e.g. course id 274 has 48 months and 285 has duration of 24 months and there are 3, 2 entries respectively. The problem is with course id 260 which is 24 months course but has only 1 entry. The **join will not return the second year** for that course.

```
df11=pd.read_csv('https://s3.amazonaws.com/todel162/myso.csv')

df11.course_id.value_counts()
274    3
285    2
260    1

df=df11.merge(df11[['course_id']], on='course_id')

df.course_id.value_counts()
274    9
285    4
260    1
```

Is it possible to write a query that will also consider the number of months?

---

The following query will return the records where simple join will not return expected results.

```
df11=pd.read_csv('https://s3.amazonaws.com/todel162/myso.csv')
df11['m1']=df11.groupby('course_id').course_id.transform( lambda x: x.count() * 12) 
df11.query( 'm1  !=  duration_inmonths') 

df11.course_id.value_counts()
274    3
285    2
260    1

df=df11.merge(df11[['course_id']], on='course_id')

df.course_id.value_counts()
274    9
285    4
260    1
```

**The expected count in this case is**

```
274    6
285    4
260    2
```

This is because even if there are 3 years for id 274, the course duration is only 24 months. And even if there is only 1 record for 260 since the duration is 24 months, it should return 2 records. (once for current year and the other current_year + 1)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIUC we can [merge](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) `df11` to itself:

```
In [14]: df11.merge(df11[['course_id']], on='course_id')
Out[14]:
    course_id  AcademicYear_to  months  TotalFee
0         260             2017      24       100
1         260             2017      24       100
2         260             2018      12       140
3         260             2018      12       140
4         274             2016      36       300
5         274             2016      36       300
6         274             2016      36       300
7         274             2017      24       340
8         274             2017      24       340
9         274             2017      24       340
10        274             2018      12       200
11        274             2018      12       200
12        274             2018      12       200
13        285             2017      24       300
14        285             2017      24       300
15        285             2018      12       200
16        285             2018      12       200
```

Comment: The will work if the data is consistent. I have updated my question.

Answer (score 2):

**Not Pretty!**

```
def f(x):
    idx = x.index.remove_unused_levels()
    idx = pd.MultiIndex.from_product(idx.levels, names=idx.names)
    return x.reindex(idx)

df11.set_index(['months', 'AcademicYear_to']) \
    .groupby('course_id').TotalFee.apply(f) \
    .groupby(level=[0, 1]).transform('first') \
    .astype(df11.TotalFee.dtype).reset_index()

    course_id  months  AcademicYear_to  TotalFee
0         260      24             2017       100
1         260      24             2018       100
2         260      12             2017       140
3         260      12             2018       140
4         274      12             2016       200
5         274      12             2017       200
6         274      12             2018       200
7         274      24             2016       340
8         274      24             2017       340
9         274      24             2018       340
10        274      36             2016       300
11        274      36             2017       300
12        274      36             2018       300
13        285      24             2017       300
14        285      24             2018       300
15        285      12             2017       200
16        285      12             2018       200
```

Comment: The suggested solution works with test data. But I have a lot of columns to be repeated. Updated my question.

Comment: Left join with the original dataframe returned what I was looking for. Thanks.

Comment: Getting error: Exception: cannot handle a non-unique multi-index!